# display acf field value in single product template in woo

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

Currently I'm modifying single product in woocommerce, I created an acf field to a custom post type named recipe, I want to display recipes related to the current product based on the acf value...
here is my code

```html
/**
 * Product Recipes
 */
function show_product_recipes() {
    $product = new WC_product( get_the_ID() );
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product_recipes = get_field( 'zf_recipes', $product_id );
    // print_r( $product );

    if ( $product_recipes ) :
        echo '<div class="product-recipes">';
        echo '<h2 class="section-title">'. __( 'Product recipes', 'zumra' ) .'</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_product_recipes', 20 );
```

```html
/**
 * Product Recipes
 */
function show_product_recipes() {
    $product = new WC_product( get_the_ID() );
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product_recipes = get_field( 'zf_recipes', $product_id );
    // print_r( $product );

    if ( $product_recipes ) :
        echo '<div class="product-recipes">';
        echo '<h2 class="section-title">'. __( 'Product recipes', 'zumra' ) .'</h2>';
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_product_recipes', 20 );
```